# Форматирование вложенного кода

Tags: поддержка, редактор, форматирование, блок-кода

Поясню проблему. Я хочу сделать так:

> [image: Желаемый вид]

Однако, если сырое сообщение выглядит так:

> ```
> 1. Код
>
> int main() {}
> ```

то после выделение строки `int main() {}` мышью и нажатия на кнопку [image: кнопка выделения кода] на панели, происходит сдвиг строки кода на 4 пробела вправо, но этого не достаточно для его форматирования как `код`:

> [image: после нажатия кнопки]

Я знаю, что в таком случае можно добавить ещё 4 пробела вручную, чтобы достигнуть желаемого эффекта. И это не так сложно сделать, когда строка одна. Но когда их много, недосмотр приводит к исчезновению не отодвинутых строк при просмотре финальной ревизии. Пример, [правка номер 3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/616152/3).

Существует ли удобный способ форматирования кода, который вложен в список, средствами встроенного на сайте редактора сообщений?

Comment: да, больная тема.... это одна из причин, почему я ненавижу MD

Comment: Вообще самое логичное было бы сделать две кнопки одна для добавления 4 пробелов, другая для удаления.... CTRL+K и CTRL+L например... как в IDE (там правда таб и шифт+таб но суть та же)

Comment: Вообще было бы круто, чтобы можно было настраивать параметры форматирования, и чтобы оно применялось автоматом :-)

Comment: @Grundy а ещё менять кодировку, концовки строк win/unix, сохранение в файл, подсветка при редактировании, быстрое сравнение с предыдущей ревизией, ну и чашечку кофе с пирожком.

Comment: @alexolut, внезапно пришла мысль, что неплохо было бы дополнение какое-нибудь для браузера :-) Потому что ожидать решение от разработчиком мне кажется не стоит :)

Comment: @Grundy есть такое дополнение, называется человек :)

Comment: @alexolut, а что, в этом что-то есть :-) надо завести себе человека, который будет форматировать код в ответах/вопросах :)

Comment: Ну, вообще-то код, вызываемый по команде «отформатировать как код», должен учитывать, находимся мы внутри списка или нет. Баг на той стороне. Моё предложение — сообщить баг.

Comment: @VladD судя по [этому ответу](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3793/339911) я не уверен, что баг будет расценен как баг.

Comment: @alexolut: Ну я вроде в том ответе ничего против не заметил. (1) Код внутри списка отделяется 8-ю (или 12, 16, ...) пробелами. (2) Есть команда «превратить в код», а она работает по факту как «вставить 4 пробела». (3) Команда _может_ проанализировать отступы, найти текущий уровень списка, и вставить нужное количество пробелов. Но она этого не делает => баг.

Comment: @VladD о... там, кстати, [комментарий](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown/3793#comment823091_3793) как раз об этом. Описывающий подход, что и Qwertiy предложил в ответе.

Comment: @alexolut: Ну да, но это ж явный костыль на стороне пользователя? (Ну и комментарий вроде бы согласен со мной: «Not only counterintuitive, but annoying. I do know that if you put a single character at the beginning of a line, you can force it to move over, but that is not intuitive either...»)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский markdown незачем ненавидеть, это просто встроенный редактор не умеет работать с отступами.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну не то, чтобы совсем удобный, но я делаю так:

1. Написал список и код.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> чтобы код сдвинулся на 4 пробела.
3. В первой строке кода удалить 1 пробел (теперь их осталось 3).
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> чтобы код сдвинулся на 4 пробела (это не отмена, т. к. там 3, а не 4).
5. Вернуть пробел в первой строке.

Код в списке готов :)

Comment: Интересный способ, ничего не скажешь :)

Comment: А что, вместо норм функционала остается этот способ добавить в подсказки пользователю и считать, что бага нет))

Comment: Всегда так делаю )

Answer (score 5):

Все костыли уже изобретены до нас на [stackapps.com](https://stackapps.com/).

- [Юзерскрипт](https://stackapps.com/questions/2440), добавляющий кнопки идентации на тулбар редактора.    [[Установить]](https://github.com/H-B/StackOverflow-Indentation-Buttons-UserScript/raw/master/so-extendededitor.user.js).

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

  У меня в браузере замечен баг: превью не обновляется после применения кнопок.

---

- [Юзерскрипт](https://stackapps.com/questions/3247), который приучает редактор нормально обрабатывать многократные <kbd>Tab</kbd> и <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, как все привыкли в уютных IDE, и еще кое-что.   [[Установить]](https://bitbucket.org/balpha/se-tab-edting/raw/tip/tab-editing.user.js).

Comment: Это тоже всё замечательно. Но этим получается пользуются "избранные", которые заходят на мету например или в чате бывают и видят ссылки на это.... а как же все остальные сотни тысячи пользователей? эх. печаль. Но за скрипт спасибо)

Comment: Первый скрипт работает, классно. А с табами у меня на Yandex Browser никак на tab не реагирует.

Answer (score 1):

Еще один обходной путь для javascript - использовать сниппет.

Можно, как просто вставить сниппет, так и использовать инструменты форматирования сниппета.

Сниппет форматирует код javascript - определяя отступ по первой строке, поэтому если в ней сделать 8 пробелов, код будет отформатирован с указанным отступом. После этого его можно просто скопировать и вставить.

Comment: о, а вот этого я не знал. правда он делает отсупы 2 пробела а не 4, что не очень камильфо смотрится в целом...например для того же XML или java

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, на самом деле он только в панельке для javascript это делает, и если туда другой язык вставить, если шанс, что после форматирования все сломается. И да, в панельках для css, и html - он убирает пробельные отступы

Comment: угу, об этом я тоже думал. но для js хоть подходит уже хорошо

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, 2 пробела везде выглядят шикарно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, кроме тех мест, где выглядят не очень :)

Comment: @Grundy, так и не понял, что надо сделать, чтобы отформатировать...

Comment: @Qwertiy, открываешь сниппет, копируешь в него javascript код, в первой строке устанавливаешь сколько пробелов должен быть общий отступ, жмешь кнопку привести в порядок, и код выровнен по указанному числу пробелов.

Comment: @Grundy, и первую строку при этом не выделять. По-моему, мой способ проще :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, не понял про _и первую строку при этом не выделять_

Comment: @Grundy, если выделить всё, то первая строка встанет в 0.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а где я писал что-то про выделить: ничего выделять не надо, просто жмешь кнопку "Привести в порядок"

Comment: @Grundy, а я shift+tab использовал))) Да, с кнопкой как-то работает. Но как-то странно :D