# Хорошо бы сделать автоформатер для текста кода

Tags: предложение, редактор, форматирование

Много времени приходится тратить на форматирование кода, как своих вопросов, так и чужих. Хорошо бы сделать кнопку, которая автоматически делает форматирование кода. Хотя бы на уровне расстановки отступов.

**Добавлено** (В результате обсуждения с *Алексей Шиманский*)
Можно прямо в главном редакторе сделать кнопочку по нажатии на которой выпадает список из нескольких языков, разметок для форматирования. Нажимаешь и выделенный (или тот фрагмент кода где стоит курсор) форматируется согласно стандартному CodeStyle этого языка. Если не понравилось можно просто откатить форматирование и просто не пользоваться дальше. Конечно есть редкие ЯП, и желающие делать нестандартный CodeStyle, но это редкие случаи, а большие 90% ситуаций эта функция покроет. А то что не покрывается просто делать ручками, как и было ранее.

Comment: Теперь осталось понять, что сайт американский и пропихивать идеи, затрагивающие общий функционал, надо через Meta Stack Exchange. Но там такая [уже есть.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82671/339911)

Comment: @alexolut А администрация русского сайта никак не связана с общей системой? я подумал что если сочтут актуальным, то могли бы и личным сообщением через месенджер написать или email. Да... и той теме там 6 лет... долго тянется...

Comment: тут один человек только из "администрации". Да и штат общий недавно сократили.

Comment: @alexolut тогда ждём его в этой теме ))

Comment: Как упоминал @alexolut, подобное предложение есть на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82671/). Я уточнил его статус. Статус — никаких обновлений, ни положительных, ни отрицательных, к сожалению.

Answer (score 5):

> **@ViktorTomilov:**
>
> На базе чьих предпочтений делать такое форматирование? Я, к примеру,
> сторонник того стиля, что мне преподавали ещё в школе, но, при этом
> уважаю стиль других программистов при условии, что их стиль
> удобочитаем. И не полезу его править.

Действительно, зачем тут вообще кнопки правки? Давайте не позволять менять "авторский кривой код с выравниванием всех элементов по левому краю", а то вторгаются в личное пространство и видение автора, и банить сразу за вторжение в стиль изложения и подачи. Какая ерунда чесслово.

> **@alexolut:**
>
> Если же кто-то вставил заведомо криво отформатированный код, то
> всегда можно использовать что-то типа code beautify или другой
> сторонний инструмент с настраивавыми параметрами форматирования

А если человек вставил четыре блока с кривым форматированием, то чтобы ответить - надо четыре блока бежать улучшать? Серьзно. Что за ерунда? Код должен быть уже таким, чтобы не текла кровь из глаз. Надо уважать остальных. Хочешь ответ на вопрос - сделай всё, чтобы можно было быстро воспроизвести проблему. А для этого нужно, чтобы код уже был адекватиным с самого начала или иметь возможность быстро его поправить нажатием кнопки.

---

Вот @alexolut дал ссылку на `codebeautify.org`, где можно выбрать "Тип" форматирования, но не понял, что эту идею и можно применить.

@ДмитрийПолянин может быть не совсем корректно выразился. Да, одной кнопки "Сделай мне хорошо" недостаточно. Но можно добавить список, в котором можно как на `codebeautify.org` выбрать нужный тип. Отступ может по дефолту ставиться такой, какой принят в CodeStyle языка программирования.

Большой мутированный список не нужен. Достаточно популярных ЯП (6-7-8) и, например *Json*. Всё.

Comment: Можно прямо в главном редакторе сделать кнопочку по нажатии на которой выпадает список из нескольких языков, разметок для форматирования. Нажимаешь и выделеный (или тот фрагмент кода где стоит курсор) форматируется согласно стандартному CodeStyle этого языка. Если не понравилось можно просто откатить форматирование и просто не пользоваться дальше. Конечно есть редкие ЯП, и желающие делать нестандартный CodeStyle, но это редкие случаи, а большие 90% ситуаций эта функция покроет. А то что не покрывается просто делать ручками, как и было ранее. Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин собсн, это я и написал........Идея норм, вот только разрабы всё равно забьют на неё)

Comment: я предложил как сделать без дополнительного окна даже, на основе вашего варианта

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин да, я когда писал про окно - у меня в голове еще пара параметров крутилась. Наверное можно это подредачить, хотя с обновлением вопроса - не знаю что сделать

Comment: ну внимание обратят, а решать уже администрации, но обсудить и написать думаю точно можно ))

Comment: я тоже когда вопрос писал, понимал что просто одной кнопкой не обойтись, что тут думать надо, но подумал что конкретное решение уже можно найти общаясь сообща.

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, не стоит:

1. Как быть с языками, в которых отступы влияют на интерпретацию? Например, python.
2. На базе чьих предпочтений делать такое форматирование? Я, к примеру, сторонник того стиля, что мне преподавали ещё в школе, но, при этом уважаю стиль других программистов при условии, что их стиль удобочитаем. И не полезу его править.

Comment: может быть форматировать стандартным способ и не очень подходит, но всё же считаю что хорошо бы подумать о том как облегчить форматирование. Это могут быть и кнопки для ручного добавления удаления отступов, например, или что-то ещё...

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Вручную, на уровне нескольких кнопок, возможно, что да, идея годится для рассмотрения. Правда, опять-таки, тогда придётся делать какие-то настройки этих кнопок.

Answer (score 1):

Разные языки подразумевают разные стили, так же как и у одно и того же языка может быть много разных стилей, выбранных в качестве подходящих.

В обычной ситуации код вставляется из соответствующего редактора, в котором уже предусмотрено то или иное форматирование. Если же кто-то вставил заведомо криво отформатированный код, то всегда можно использовать что-то типа [code beautify](https://codebeautify.org/) или другой сторонний инструмент с настраивавыми параметрами форматирования.

Comment: Вот в том то и дело что подставляя из редактора код ломается. Отступы редактора добавляются к отступам в сообщении, например в C# может быть много внешних блоков, такие как namespace или class, а если я вставляю код функции класса, то появляется куча новых отступов, которые приходится ручками вычищать. Да, согласен, языки разные бывают, но можно придумать какую-то функциональность для работы с отступами хотя бы. Например выделил фрагмент и евиличил/уменьшил все отступы выделенного фрагмента, такая функциональность есть например в VisualStudio.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин можно поиграться с [такими комбинациями.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4574/176217)

Comment: установил дополнение с кнопками, думаю это частично решает проблему, спасибо