# Пожалуйста, оставьте ваш отзыв о Stack Overflow за 2017 год!

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено

Подскажите, были ли моменты, когда вам казалось, что если бы на сайте было реализовано что–то, если бы мы вместе приняли какое–то решение по организации процессов либо внедрили инициативу, то ваша жизнь в сообществе стала бы легче, приятнее, продуктивнее? Возможно, у вас есть какое–то особое мнение о развитии сайта, целях сообщества или наболевшая тема? *Расскажите об этом!*

Пожалуйста, заполните форму: https://goo.gl/uCeWT4. Форма анонимная, ответить на вопросы можно лишь один раз. Скорее всего, написание ответов не займет у вас более 15 минут.

Ваше мнение обязательно будет услышано! Я постараюсь сделать все возможное, чтобы все, о чем вы напишите, при необходимости и возможности было рассмотрено, ошибки учтены, рекомендации выполнены.

Stack Overflow (компании) и мне лично крайне важно ваше мнение, идеи и мысли о сайте и сообществе. Мы хотим вместе создать лучшую, *по мнению сообщества*, систему накопления и многократного использования накопленных знаний. Для нас очень важно, чтобы всем пользователям и участникам было приятно и полезно использовать сайт.

[Пройти опрос »](https://goo.gl/uCeWT4)

Сбор отзывов продлится до 10-го января 2018 года.

С нетерпением ждем ваших отзывов!

Comment: «Чтобы заполнить форму, войдите в аккаунт Google
В этой форме есть функции, для использования которых необходимо войти в аккаунт.» — а что делать тем, у кого такого аккаунта нет?

Comment: А если хочется неанонимно и ответом в этом топике, м?

Comment: @VladD тогда можно оставить отзыв за 2017 год до н.э. в форме наскальной живописи.

Comment: @VladD Опубликовать отзыв можно прямо здесь в ответе или отправить ответы мне на почту.

Comment: Я своё предложение уже писал, но администрация на него никак не отреагировала. Да, возможно прочитала, но хочется и отклика со стороны работников SO - https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6627/Хорошо-бы-сделать-автоформатер-для-текста-кода . Вообще в результате того обсуждения у меня сложилось унылое впочатление о возможности обратной связи в SO, возможно ошибочное.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Вы опубликовали запрос нововведения. Здесь, скорее, было бы здорово услышать не только какие–то отдельные технические нововведения, но и общие, организационные моменты. Подскажите, есть ли что–то помимо автоматического форматирование кода, что сделает вашу жизнь (и жизнь ваших коллег) в сообществе и за его пределами много лучше?

Answer (score 13):

Я написал в отзыве, но напишу это и здесь, так как не думаю, что отзывы много кто читать будет.

Я вижу главную и, на мой взгляд, очень серьезную проблему в том, что русский SO из ресурса для профессионалов стремительно превращается в ресурс для ленивых студентов. Одним лень подумать, погуглить и книжку почитать (и имя им легион), а другим хочется потешить себя вновь заработанными баллами, независимо от того, знают они тему или не очень, умеют формулировать свои мысли или нет. В результате SO превращается в коллекцию решений домашних заданий, курсовых и контрольных, причем решения эти далеко не всегда хороши. Профессионалам это не интересно и не полезно, они уходят или просто не участвуют, в результате доля интересных и актуальных для профессионала  вопросов и качественных ответов на такие вопросы снижается, в результате профессионалам это становится еще менее интересно, и таким образом SO катится вниз по наклонной.

Кроме того, потворство ленивым студентам я вообще считаю делом крайне вредным. Сегодня они свои контрольные выкладывают в виде вопросов на SO и сдают преподавателям полученные ответы, а завтра они идут на работу и пишут банковские системы, где персональные данные о счетах клиентов доступны всем желающим, или пишут программы для разгонных блоков "фрегат", не зная, как градусы в радианы пересчитать.

Я думаю, что с этим надо что-то делать, если мы хотим сохранить русский SO в качестве ресурса, полезного программистам, а не только студентам. На мой взгляд, следовало бы четче проработать политику, направленную на поддержание качества SO и на предотвращение его деградации, твердо и последовательно проводить эту политику в жизнь и обязательно знакомить с этой политикой новичков, чтобы они с самого начала чётко понимали, куда они попали и чем (и зачем) здесь занимаются.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв! Было бы очень интересно наглядно посмотреть на проблему. Пожалуйста, не могли бы вы как–то подкрепить ваши выводы ссылками? Будет совсем здорово, если вы в минимальном виде покажете проблему на [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/).  На данный момент, как мне кажется, вы формулируете вопрос, который был рассмотрен очень много раз, [в том числе, в приближенном виде совсем недавно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6599/6). Везде и всюду мы видели, что как только мы убираем эмоции из подобных утверждений, переходим к реальным цифрам, сразу видим, что реали выглядят иначе.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, я не знаю, как цифры могут подвердить или опровергнуть то, о чем я говорю. Я говорю не о популярности, не о количестве вопросов или просмотров, а о качестве и полезности контента. Даже баллы, полученные вопросом или ответом, не могут точно отражать его качество, так как голоса всех участников равноценны и не зависят от квалификации. Я говорю в первую очередь о своем субъективном ощущении: я усматриваю довольно отчетливую тенденцию к снижению общего уровня. Не количество вопросов и ответов вообще, и не быллы, а именно средний уровень качества, доля хороших постов.

Comment: Я абсолютно ничего не имею против новичков, студентов и начинающих программистов, как против глупых вопросов, и сам порой отвечаю на такие вопросы. Но поощрение откровенной лени снижает качество ресурса и его привлекательность для профессионалов. Да, вы правы, сходные вопросы ставились здесь неоднократно, но никаких решений, которые могли бы остановить эту тенденцию, как мне кажется, принято не было, соответвтено, не было принято и никаких мер.

Comment: @m.vokhm 1- *ноль ссылок*, не смотря на многочисленные многолетние обсуждения этой темы. Это не личная атака, просто наблюдение, что люди озабоченные чужой леностью, часто её демонстрируют :) 2- *"субъективное ощущение"* важнее фактов. Я помню ещё в 2008 году о Stack Overflow похожие суждения люди высказывали (и до сих пор продолжают высказывать). Ни до ни сейчас нет ресурса с лучшим сигнал/шум соотношением при схожей широте охвата тем¶ Многие моменты можно улучшить конечно, но для этого не "субъективные ощущения", а знакомство с конкретными цифрами может помочь.

Comment: Я получаю от Stackoverflow большую реальную помощь в своей работе, и мне бы хотелось, чтобы руccкий snakoverflow был также полезен не только студентам, но и профессиональным программистам, именно поэтому я и высказываю свое беспокойство. Ну и к тому же, вы сами просили высказать свое мнение.

Comment: @jfs я не привожу ссылок не из-за лени, а по таким причинам: 1) Я не собирал ссылок на плохие вопросы, поскольку не планировал обсуждать эту тему; 2) Каждый видел сам множество примеров тому, о чем я говорю; 3) Мне не хотелось бы выставлять людей редисками, лодырями и бездарями, указывая на них пальцем, даже если их вопросы мне не нравятся. Но если без указания конкретных примеров трудно понять, о чем я говорю, то я мог бы привести несколько примеров. Ресурс замечательный, с этим я не спорю, я говорю об опасности его деградации. Как измерить полезность цифрами, я не знаю.

Comment: @m.vokhm ссылки на предыдущие обсуждения на Мете — вы не первый кто не понимает миссию SO  (ценность сайта в наличие ответов на вопросы которые у реальных людей возникают, а не а борьбе с леностью. Подробнее, можете к примеру на мои ответы посмотреть на Мете на эту тему).

Comment: @jfs я уже смотрел, конечно, но и еще посмотрю и подумаю. Я отнюдь не считаю борьбу с чужой ленью миссией SO, но я думаю, что согласно первоначальному замыслу SO должен приносить пользу в первую очередь программистам, настоящим и будущим, а всем прочим, чья цель сдать и забыть -- лишь постольку, поскольку это не мешает основной задаче. Если это так, то я думаю, что качество вопросов и ответов должно быть важнее их количесва.

Comment: @m.vokhm и эта и многие другие мысли уже ранее адресованы на Мете.

Comment: @m.vokhm «_никаких решений, которые могли бы остановить эту тенденцию, как мне кажется, принято не было, соответственно, не было принято и никаких мер._» — возможно, потому и не было мер, так как нет проблемы, или проблема недостаточно исследована или ясна.  _Каждый видел сам множество примеров тому, о чем я говорю_ — вопрос спорный. Я, например, не вижу их и, как результат, прошу показать мне и всем остальным проблему в самом плохом из ее проявлений. Мета на то и нужна, чтобы обсуждать проблемы сообщества открыто!

Comment: [Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что проблемы можно и нужно обсуждать без привязки к автору конкретного вопроса, ответ или нарушителю какого–либо правила](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4790/6). Наша цель — создать лучшие процессы, улучшить движок сайта, а не бороться и уж тем более наказать кого–либо в индивидуальном порядке. Любое обсуждение на Мете, пусть даже с вполне конкретным примером, направлено на дискус всего сайта целиком, как можно более критичнее, с обоснованием и, по возможности, с цифрами.

Comment: Я считаю ваше мнение ошибкой, к сожалению крайне распространенной среди местных пользователей, "закрывашек" здесь много. "SO должен приносить пользу..." - вот этого достаточно, без всяких в первую очередь, во вторую, и т.д. Если взять тех, "чья цель сдать и забыть", то обычно мы не умеем читать мысли, и как следствие не можем сказать, что побудило ТС - лень или он действительно не может найти ответ на какой либо "тривиальный" вопрос.

Comment: Многие "тривиальные" вопросы не расматриваются в специальной литературе, вследствии своей "тривиальности" (например разница = и == в С++), либо рассматриваются в каких либо "нетривиальных" для начинающего разделах (например вопросы локализации).

Comment: Я поддерживаю эту инициативу. Сситема рейтинга здесь работает в минус. Дело в том что специалисту ответить на вопрос халявщика может быть очень просто, даже когда этого делать не надо, но он может это сделать из-за репутации. Я стараюсь сам по возможности не отвечать на такие вопросы, но, честно говоря, игра в репутацию затягивает часто и меня, и я принимаю решение отвечать не из реальной целесообразности а из желания заработать рейтинг.

Comment: Да, теперь я вижу, что неправильно понимал задачи SO. Но тогда я не понимаю, почему заминусовали вот этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766379/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81-java-%d0%bd%d0%b0-php.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky вам нужны ссылки? ну вот вам [свежая](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766800/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5/). Как думаете что я сделал что бы дать ответ по языку на котором никогда не кодил? Набрал в гугле "C# base". За этот простой ответ меня не заминусовали, а дали +2. А у автора этого вопроса репа почти в 2 раза больше чем у меня.

Comment: А зачем отвечать на сложные вопросы? Все ответы на сложные вопросы остаются неоцененными. А зачем задавать сложные вопросы если на них сможешь ответить только ты после месяца изучения? [ссылка1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/651652/Как-исправить-reduce-reduce-конфликт), [ссылка2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/647313/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be)

Comment: @ИльяЧижанов Подскажите, что плохого/неправильного в том, что вам за правильный ответ дали два голоса за? [Смотрите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1813/6), у меня не менее тривиальный, на мой взгляд, ответ получил +218! Тривиальный он для _меня_, и не потому что я какой–то там «гуру», нет, просто я знаю ответ именно на этот вопрос. Выставите ли вы и меня полным глупцом за [подобный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/629551/6)? Он тривиален и прост! Но не для меня, а для того, кто знает на него ответ!

Comment: Ваши ответы кому–то полезны и чем больше людей увидит ответ, тем больше проголосует за или против (голая статистика)! Чем распространенней знание (чем более они базовое), тем больше им интересуются, тем больше внимания со стороны коллег они получат. Да, иногда, за ответ на распространенный вопрос можно получить больше голосов, чем на более сложный узкоспециализированный. Вопрос не в количестве голосов «за», а в ваших личных целях. Если вы хотите упражняться в простых задачах, пожалуйста, отвечайте на простые вопросы, если в задачах посложнее — это ваш выбор!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я наверное не точно описал проблему. Проблема никак не в глупых вопросах, а в ленивых. ВЫ знали ответ на [ЭТОТ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1813/6) вопрос. Но вот я свой ответ не знал и уж точно я не гуру. Просто потратил 2 минуты на гугл по ключевой фразе. Гугля "пустая функция main" я сразу же попадаю на SO с правильным ответом, благодаря вам, вот это знак качества. Я думаю каждый программист прежде чем задавать вопрос сначала попытается найти на него ответ, изучить вопрос самостоятельно, а если не смог то задаёт его на SO.

Comment: @ИльяЧижанов Так и происходит! Проблема новичка в том, что он не знает, что не работает, не понимает, что надо искать! Лучше всего понять это, если взяться за что–то совсем новое и неизвестное. К примеру, для меня это языки. [Вот](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/436171/), вероятно, простой «ленивый» вопрос. Но проблема в том, что я не просто не знаю как правильно поставить вопрос поисковику, я даже не понимаю какие метки следует добавить к вопросу на сайте (я действительно зашел в список меток и читал их описания, чтобы задать хотя бы текущие)!

Comment: Пожалуйста, для эксперимента, возьмите любую совершенно не знакомую вам и более или менее сложную науку, и попробуйте разобраться в каком–либо вопросе базового уровня. Вы непременно поймете, что рассказы про лень, лишь рассказы. Когда вы тратите с пол часа лишь на выбор правильных меток — это ленью не назовешь! Скопировать ответ с SO много сложнее, чем задать его на SO! Почему же мы зовем «лентяями» тех, кто тратит сильно больше времени на поиск ответа, чем мы сами? Проблема изучающего не в лени, а в незнании предметной области.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky изучение любой науки должно начинаться с изучения предметной области. SO это сообщество экспертов, а не сообщество преподавателей или я ошибаюсь? Видя вопрос в ленте я хочу быть уверенным что человек приложил хотя бы немного своих сил что бы разобраться в свой проблеме.

Comment: @ИльяЧижанов Конечно, хотелось бы! Проблема в том, что я лично не вижу способа отличить невежду от не знающего ([смежный вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4882/6)). Понимая, что найти информацию в поиске много проще, чем задать вопрос, я лично допускаю, что все–таки, за крайне редким исключением, люди пытались найти что–то. Как минимум, они нашли наш сайт, что уже свидетельствует о том, что они что–то искали. Но много важнее другое! Пожалуйста, помните: мы не помогаем конкретным людям, мы создаем базу знаний для всего сообщества, что имеет много большее значение!

Comment: Ну очень уж понравилась цитата, по-моему, как раз о ruSO :) - *I think this is one of the most important things I've learned as I've progressed as a programmer:

A good programmer knows how to ask questions without being annoying. A great programmer knows how to answer questions without being a jerk.* [Steven Hirlston, Ruby on Rails Back End Developer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-programmer-a-good-programmer-and-a-great-programmer-What-is-the-path-of-becoming-a-great-programmer/answer/Steven-Hirlston)

Answer (score 6):

> Пожалуйста, подскажите, какие технические нововведения или процессы
>   организации сообщества смогут сделать ваше участие в сообществе легче,
>   приятнее, продуктивнее?

1.
Разрешение Room Owner-ам давать права на доступ к чату в случаях, если у пользователя еще нет 20 репутации.

2.
Снижение времени ожидания для доступа пользователям к системе чатов. Порой проходит до нескольких часов (эмпирическое наблюдение) прежде чем появляются права после получения необходимого количества репутации.

> Чего сегодня не хватает сообществу по вашему мнению?

1.
Конкретики. Прячась за абстрагированием актуальность (а иногда даже сама возможность сформулировать) проблем теряется из-за того, что большинство "нарушений" отмечаемых сообществом являются ситуативными, а не систематическими.

2.
Контроля. В том случае если вопросы все-таки поднимаются решения не принимаются.

[На каких основаниях модератор может восстанавливать ответ, удаленный автором?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6672/%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC)

> Какие проблемы в сообществе вы видите?

1.
Большое количество закрытых вопросов из-за непонимания новичков куда они попали.

2.
(частично следствие из 1) После закрытого (первого) вопроса люди не занимаются исправлением указанных ошибок и не возвращаются на сайт обратно.

3.
Низкое качество задаваемых вопросов, что беспокоит сообщество. С завидной периодичностью проблема поднимается снова и снова.

[Ресурс из базы знаний для специалистов превращается в консультационный пункт новичков](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/616/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2)

> Что по вашему мнению необходимо сделать, чтобы сообщество динамично
>   развивалось?

Решить существующие проблемы, разумеется =)

Возможный путь решения.

Выделить специальную чат комнату доступ к который будет  у всех участников (а не с 20). Назначение комнаты - получение помощи для грамотной формулировки вопроса.

Ваш вопрос закрыли и вы не знаете что делать? Не паникуйте - получите консультацию у сообщества в заранее приготовленном месте.

Comment: Хм, будем не только решать задачи студентов, но и помогать им написать корректное условие, так чтобы рука не поднялась закрыть вопрос

Comment: @АндрейNOP из некоторых учебных задач можно сделать хорошие вопросы. Самая часто допускаемая ошибка -- вывалить в вопрос задание целиком вместо того, чтобы изолировать конкретный непонятый момент. Если на неё сразу укажут, это даже к лучшему.

Comment: @АндрейNOP именно, чтобы в следующий раз человек пришел с правильным вопросом или даже ответом.

Answer (score 3):

StackOverflow - это очень хороший сайт, отличный сайт, замечательный, где можно получить ответы от профессионалов. 
Но единственное, я вроде бы не создаю особо плохих вопросов, а мне иногда блокируют возможность задавать новые вопросы. Это неудобно. 
Хотелось бы иметь возможность задавать больше вопросов, получать на них квалифицированные ответы и хотелось бы, вследствие этого, становиться профессионалом.

Comment: Если вы попали в Question Ban из-за заминусованных вопросов, можно попытаться выбраться из него с помощью ответов. Отвечайте на легкие вопросы, в которых разбираетесь. Ответы на легкие вопросы охотно плюсуют, а голоса за ответы, насколько я знаю, учитываются в критерях Question Ban.

Answer (score 2):

Я недавно узнал про этот сайт, и очень хорошо, что он есть, но за 3 недели я тоже заметил стремление некоторых не быть полезным, не учить и подсказать, не узнать и выучить, а заработать баллы. Еслибы за неуместный положительный или отрицательный отзыв люди лишились бы этих самых баллов(своего рода штраф), немного все изменится к лучшему. Это не значит, что я недоволен, наоборот, я даже готов выразить свою благодарность организаторам, работникам и участникам... Но а жаловаться на вопросы студентов и других начинающих, это не очень умно и благородно. Все когда то были студентами и новычками, и все имеют право пользоваться хорошим источником, да и никто не мешает профессионалам просто  никак не отзываться или голосовать против конкретного вопроса. Среди этих самых профессионалов я  всретил человека, который ведет себя некорректно в оценках и комментах,  думаю и против таких должны быть жесткие меры. А в целом нужно быть доброжелательным ко всем пользователям - ведь именно пользователи обеспечивают живучесть сайта...

Comment: Если речь об оскорблениях, то да, за них есть штрафы к репутации. Кидайте тревоги "Спам/Оскорбление".

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight я думаю, речь о «моему сообщению хулиганы поставили минус, вопиющее поведение, расстрелять!»

Comment: совсем наоборот -  дело  в том что человек имеющий 20K репутации   обижается, когда доказываешь, что его критика неверна  и от обиды начинает ставить эти минусы и явно просит автору принять его ответ ,  и это при тривиальной задаче. Программирование не  моя профессия, и для меня эти минусы и плюсы не имеют значения.  Речь о том, что не только среди новычков есть люди, из за которых пропадает охота заходить в сайт...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan есть ли конкретный пример(ссылка) данного "спора" ? интересно посмотреть что вы доказываете и по какой причине "обижаються" и отрекаются от истины, если есть такова. Может вы не верно поняли данную "критику" ?

Comment: *"Еслибы за неуместный положительный или отрицательный отзыв люди лишились бы этих самых баллов"* -- в том, что касается тематики сайта, Stack Overflow забивает на отдельных участников, а оперирует массой людей. И превалируют **популярные** мнения. На которые вполне можно влиять путём демонстрации конкретных убедительных фактов, подкреплённых технически или авторитетом источников. На непопулярные мнения отдельных участников система просто не акцентирует внимание.

Comment: А что касается студентов -- студент студенту рознь. Есть студенты, которые учатся, пытаются решить задание сами и вежливо просят пояснить конкретный непонятый момент (если, конечно, ответ уже не нашёлся до этого времени в других вопросах или иных источниках информации). А есть студенты, которые вбухивают в вопрос скриншот бумажки с куском задания и требуют решить.

Comment: @D-side  да, вы правы, но и есть такие, которые достигают приличных знаний и неуважительно относятся к тем, кто еще только учится,  и в моей жизни  я встречал много таких начиная с ВУЗ а (мне 53 года). К сожалению иногда себя тоже ловил с таким поведением, хотя быстро исправлялся....

Comment: За каждый минус ответа/вопроса пользователь получает -2 балла тоже, но когда у тебя 5/10/20К баллов, тебе пофиг, хоть сотню минусов можно поставить. ТС кажется предлагает ужесточить правила, чем больше рейтинга у пользователя, тем больше баллов отнимается за каждый минус, чтобы неповадно было))

Comment: @DaemonHK э, нет, во-первых -1, во-вторых только для голосов против ответов (минусы вопросам бесплатные). Но да, при тысячах репутации это действительно тонет в прочих изменениях.

Comment: @D-side я получал по -2 балла, может поменяли уже

Comment: @DaemonHK нет, уже много лет так. Как минимум всё то время, что я был на Stack Exchange. -2 прилетает за входящие минусы ответу, -1 за исходящий минус ответу.

Comment: @Arsen,  мне не интересно продолжить тему о меркантильных людей,  а мне интересно, чтоб люди понели, что меньше  мешают  ученики, чем плохие учителья...  P. S. И я еще не перестал понимать тривиальные вещи.

Answer (score 0):

Я не успел пройти опрос, так что отвечу здесь.

> Пожалуйста, подскажите, какие технические нововведения или процессы
>   организации сообщества смогут сделать ваше участие в сообществе легче,
>   приятнее, продуктивнее?

Озвучу несколько идей:

- Я бы очень хотел, чтобы несколько людей могли объявлять конкурс, т.е. каждый бы внес свою долю.
- Просмотр графика набирания репутации ближе, т.е. просмотр более мелких участков.
- Отображение изменения репутации на кубке при минусах.
- Улучшить редактор кода.

> Чего сегодня не хватает сообществу по вашему мнению?

Не хватает понятия о том, что такое репутация. Все работают и отвечают исключительно за репутацию, не понимая, что это всего лишь абстрактные цифры. И до тех пор, пока не объявишь конкурс на сложный вопрос, никто не ответит.

> Какие проблемы в сообществе вы видите?

Очень часто я вижу вопросы, которые либо вообще не относятся к программированию, либо очень непонятные. Я бы предложил сделать как на Хабре: пока справку не прочтешь, пост не напишешь! Также и здесь: пока тур не пройдешь, вопрос не задашь!

> Что по вашему мнению необходимо сделать, чтобы сообщество динамично
>   развивалось?

Мне кажется, оно и так очень быстро развивается, и я думаю что решение проблем, описанных вверху, будет достаточно.