# На каких основаниях модератор может восстанавливать ответ, удаленный автором?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, модерация

Наблюдаю странную картину - [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/766606/177188) на вопрос заминусован, автор его удаляет, а модератор восстанавливает, ответ продолжает собирать минусы. **На каких основаниях модератор может восстанавливать ответ, удаленный автором?**

*Я бы не хотел оказаться в подобной ситуации. Может быть правильнее было бы, если модератор уверен, что ответ достоин сохранения - перенести текст ответа в вики-ответ?*

> [image: Список редакций ответа]

Comment: Qwertiy буянит иногда)

Comment: @andreymal я, конечно, за него очень рад, но хотелось бы получить ответ от его "коллег по цеху" - когда и как такое приемлимо и практикуется.

Comment: Нашлось обсуждение в чате, с точкой зрения модератора (https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42094825#42094825)

Comment: @andreymal не оправдание ни разу

Comment: Когда-то в чате попросил помощи в восстановлении [вопроса удалённого, вероятно, в панике](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/696406/revisions), когда ТС понял(-а?), что находится на русскоязычном SO. Но вопрос был интересным. Это так, смежный опыт.

Answer (score 4):

Считаю, что восстановление заминусованных и удалённых автором вопросов/ответов (да и вообще любых сообщений любого участника) должно быть доступно всем и должно восприниматься как стандартная процедура. Естественно, восстанавливать следует только хорошие сообщения.

Проблема в том, что для просмотра удалённых сообщений нужно [много репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user). Таким образом у нас всего 35 человек (включая модераторов) с возможностью восстановить удалённое сообщение. К тому же надо 3 голоса для восстановления удалённого сообщения. Т.е. нужно участие почти 10% всех участников с такой возможность. Т.е. восстановить удалённые вопросы - сложно. К тому же только модераторы получают уведомления о массовых удалениях.

Я лично наблюдал ситуации, когда ТС удалял свои старые неотвеченные и незаплюсованные вопросы, т.к. считал, что они захламляют сайт. Мы, модераторы, восстанавливаем такие вопросы, если находим их полезными, руководствуясь возможной будущей пользой от них другим участникам.

Ещё был вот такой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/763910/17609). За 5 минут после публикации он был заминусован и удалён ТС-ом. Как позже выяснилось - зря. Я его восстановил, плюсанул, в коммент написал "ата-та" и ответ написал. В итоге вопрос и ответы заплюсованы и полезны.

Итого:

1. Автор сообщения не является его единоличным владельцем. Вопрос - достояние сообщества. Если вопрос/ответ хороший - его удаление - вандализм.
2. Восстанавливать и просматривать удалённые вопросы и ответы - редкая привилегия (в рамках движка сайта) и большую часть этой работы вынужденно делают модераторы.
3. Минусующие не всегда правы. Даже заминусованный вопрос/ответ может быть полезным. В этом случае, конечно, надо привлечь к нему внимание и попросить сообщество накидать плюсов.
4. В данном конкретном случае надо рассматривать не правомочность действий модератора, но качество и полезность восстановленного сообщения.

Comment: На п.4 хорошо бы услышать ответ.

Comment: @alexolut, ну, на мой взгляд, данный вопрос - оффтоп. Засим и ответ не нужен. Т.е. они удалены правильно)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб поэтому надо дать по лбу товарищу Qwertiy чтоб не восстанавливал всякое...

Comment: Квертий модератор проактивный. По лбу дать каждый может... Но можно ли дать по лбу так, чтобы проактивность не сменилась депрессией? Я просто не сторонник убивать увлечённость в людях. Ответ Юрия очень хорош и указывает направление зоны ближайшего развития: если мы хотим коллегиальности (как механизма некоторой гарантии от единоличных ошибок), то можно подумать о том, как расширить число участников с правом восстанавливать сообщение. Как вариант – снизить порог репутации для.

Comment: @AK `можно ли дать по лбу так, чтобы проактивность не сменилась депрессией?` - то есть давайте позволять делать что душе заблагорассудится, лишь бы грустно не стало? Серьезно? Может маньяков тоже не стоит сажать в тюрьмы, а то они там тоскуют же. Нипачилавечиски какта. А заниматься деятельностью готовы и другие участники вполне. Незаменимых нет, как говорится

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Пожалуйста, не приписывайте мне то, чего я не говорил. А то так легко выйти за рамки конструктивной дискуссии, чего лично мне не хотелось бы.

Comment: @AK чтобы никто не приписывал ничего словам, не надо их так очевидно выражать.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, когда удаляется вопорс, ответ удалется вместе с ним. И при желаении, вместе с ним восстанавливается. Почему ты считаешь, что конкретный ответ должен быть дополнительно удалён независимо от вопроса?

Comment: @Qwertiy ну например потому, что 1) ответу не место быть на сайте в любом случае. 2) авторм ответа сам решил удалить его 3) в результате не удаленности ответа, который не должен быть на сайте ТС мог принять ответ, залетные гонцы проголосовать "ЗА" ответ с галкой - а это накладывает свой отпечаток на принятие решений на удаление вопроса (кстати который скорее был бы просто закрыт). Так что тут проблемы очевидны.

Comment: @Qwertiy и, думаю, ты это вполне сам понимаешь и именно поэтому восстановил ответ. Иначе непонятно зачем восстанавливать ответ, если ты знаешь, что вопрос будет удален. Г - логика?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я вижу по-другому: автора ответа запугали минусами, при этом ответ ничем не хуже вопроса и причин его удалять нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy напугали или не напугали, суть 1) автор удалил свой ответ САМ 2) даже если он не удалил бы сам - ответ как и вопрос - не является нужным на ресурсе и является мусорным, который необходимо чистить 3) как следствие - был восстановлен не полезный ответ, а мусор, что, очевидно, неправильно. И автор продолжал собирать минусы, на которые модератор его обрёк. большое спасибо

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, но потом всё вместе с вопросом было удалено.

Comment: @Qwertiy я уже писал - что этого могло не быть, в следствие чего был бы а) мусор б) автор ответа, не желающий получать минусы за мусорный ответ на мусорный вопрос  продолжал бы их получать

Answer (score 3):

Пока что могу представить себе только 1 возможный сценарий, в котором это приемлемо и даже желательно: **если ответ удалён в процессе целенаправленного вредительства**.

Удаленные вопросы и ответы нужно восстанавливать, если их удаление вызвано активным вредительством (например rage-quitting или была скомпрометированна учетка). Подобные случаи достаточно легко заметить - удаляются хорошие/заплюсованные ответы (аналогично, если их текст подменяется на мусор).

Comment: `удаляются хорошие/заплюсованные ответы` — а здесь случай прямо противоположный.