# Улучшить редактор вопросов и ответов

Tags: предложение

Предлагаю добавить функциональность форматирования отступов в редакторе вопросов и ответов.

**1 вариант, самый простой.**

Две кнопки "прибавить отступ" и "убавить" добавляют и убавляют по N (2, 3 или 4) пробела у каждой строчки выделенного текста.

Такая функциональность уже есть в плагине - [Increase/Decrease Indentation Buttons for the Editor](https://stackapps.com/questions/2440/increase-decrease-indentation-buttons-for-the-editor), но минус тот что про этот плагин знают единицы.
Кроме того он не работает при редактирвоании (баг).

**2 вариант.**

Кнопка форматировать код, при нажатии на неё выпадает список из нескольких основных языков, форматирование делается дефолтным форматером для данного языка.

**Зачем это надо?**

- При вставке большого кода например из VisualStudio и из многих других редакторов появляются куча лишних пробелов, которые портят отображение текста. На ручное удаление уходит много времени.
- Когда код вставляет новичок которые вообще не в курсе о стандартах оформления вопросов. Такие вопросы приходится редактировать и много времени уходит по сути в пустую, на убирание этих пробелов.

Это время можно было бы провести с большей пользой как для себя так и для сообщества.

Идеи взяты из вопроса - [Хорошо бы сделать автоформатер для текста кода](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6627/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).

Comment: Я не понимаю, чем это лучше существующей кнопки Ctrl+K, я [как и Jeff нажал бы её семь раз](https://stackapps.com/a/2442). Что-то лучше? Ну, было бы неплохо, но не то, чтобы прямо жизненно важная для меня фича.

Comment: "добавляют и убавляют по четыре пробела" -- почему именно 4, а не 2 или 3?

Comment: @D-side очевидно можно сделать и 2 и 3, сейчас исправлю в тексте

Answer (score 6):

> Две кнопки "прибавить отступ" и "убавить" добавляют и убавляют по четыре пробела у каждой строчки выделенного текста.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> увеличивает отступ на 4 в случае, если хотя бы одна выделенная строка имеет меньше 4 пробелов в начале. Если 4 или больше, то уменьшает. При отступах в 4 пробела этого вполне достаточно (есть момент со списком, но тоже легко обходится). При отступах в 2 пробела может остаться 2 - нехорошо, да. Но это и предложенный вариант не решает.

> Кнопка форматировать код, при нажатии на неё выпадает список из нескольких основных языков, форматирование делается дефолтным форматером для данного языка.

Я против. Я не хочу чтобы мой код движок форматировал как ему вздумается. И я не хочу, чтобы код тех, кто вообще не умеет форматировать код, автоматически форматировался. Я хочу различать уровень разработчиков, задающих вопрос и форматирование кода в этом очень помогает.

> Ясно. Можно и по двум пробелам сделать. То что я предложил это же не конечный вариант, можно обсуждать.

Я за такой вариант: если все выделенные строки начинаются с пробела, но этих пробелов 4 или менее, то сдвигать до нулевого отступа. Сейчас только 4 превращается в 0, а если во всех строках 2, то станет 6. Правда, возникнет проблема со [способом получения 8 пробелов](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4574/178988) - надо что-то подумать. Но вариант, когда во всех строках осталось 2 - довольно распространённый.

Comment: Так если ты не хочешь код автоматически форматировать так можешь просто не использовать эту функцию. Я думаю кто не понимает зачем нужно форматирование и кнопкой форматирования врятли пользоваться будут. ТЕм более такая функция ест в сниппете. А на уменьшение отступа есть хоткей?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, и увеличение, и уменьшение делается нажатием Ctrl+K.

Comment: Если у меня несколько функций в коде, необходимо сделать два отступа, Ctrl + K этого сделать не позволяет.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, сниппет пишется прям в сниппете и запускается - по сути это нечто вроде IDE. А вот откуда может взяться неотформатированный код, вставляемый в вопрос? Если код пишется прямо в вопросе без проверки, то это обычно так себе вопрос, потому что проблема на коде из вопроса не воспроизводится, даже если в нём исправить все опечатки и ошибки компиляции. А если потенциального источника плохо отформатированного кода нет, то нет причин и решать такую проблему.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, код в списке? https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4574/178988
Или 2 пробела? По двум пробелам я был бы за, но ты этого не предложил.

Comment: Сниппет только для HTML кода, а для C# я копирую код из VS обычно.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, но код в VS уже хорошо отформатирован. Максимум, что требуется - удалить лишние отступы. Ctrl+K с этим справляется.

Comment: Ясно. Можно и по двум пробелам сделать. То что я предложил это же не конечный вариант, можно обсуждать.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Можно конкретные реализации форматирования предлагать в ответах, и уже за них голосовать. Сейчас свои вынесу в ответы. Я в вопросе больше хотел показать нужность этого, а реализацию, конечно надо обсудить так же как и все тонкности.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, а я в ответе хотел показать ненужность функциональности по форматированию. Убрать 2 пробела - да, нужно. Отформатировать код под какой-то стайлгайд - нет.

Answer (score 2):

На StackApps есть уже несколько готовых скриптов для вас:

- [Кнопки Reduce Indentation / Increase Indentation](https://stackapps.com/questions/2440/increase-decrease-indentation-buttons-for-the-editor)
  [image: введите сюда описание изображ]
- [Переработка механизма работы](https://stackapps.com/questions/3247/better-handling-of-indentation-and-the-tab-key-when-editing-posts) <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>
- ["Как в Notepad++ "](https://stackapps.com/questions/5038/se-like-i-like-it-userscript)(<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Comment: 1ый работает только при создании но не при редактировании, 2ой вообще не работает у меня, браузер Yandex, но дополнения для хрома обычно работают, сейчас третий проверю

Comment: третий работает, спасибо

Comment: Сам пользуюсь первым, нареканий нет.

Comment: Интересно, сейчас первый и на редактирование заработал. А раньше не работал. Может в некоторых ситуациях не работает... Я хоткеи не очень люблю, люблю кнопки, так что первый мне наиболее нравится при корректной работе.

Answer (score 1):

К полю ввода можно подключить **настоящий** редактор кода (самостоятельный, вне браузера) и получить заодно реалтаймовую подсветку, поиск/замену и другие возможности редактора и его расширений (если есть автоформаттер, можно и его):

- Через [GhostText](https://github.com/GhostText/GhostText): Chrome/Firefox + Sublime Text/Atom/VS Code/Vim/Neovim/Emacs
- Через [Atomic Chrome](https://atom.io/packages/atomic-chrome): Chrome + Atom

Comment: Мы поощряем написание кода примера прямо в вопросе? Как правило, в таком случае получаются плохие вопросы, на коде из которых (даже после исправления опечаток) описываемая проблема не воспроизводится. То же самое касается ответов - если ответ - это не одна строчка кода (а одну уж как-нибудь сам отформатируешь), то код из ответа, весьма вероятно, решать проблему из вопроса не будет (хотя может давать верное или неверное направление, куда капать). Вопрос - какие плюсы-то?

Comment: @Qwertiy плюсы уже описаны в ответе, а какое отношение весь остальной комментарий имеет к ответу, мне решительно непонятно. Если он адресован автору вопроса, под вопросом это стоит и оставить.

Comment: К вопросу я написал в ответе. А к ответу тоже пригодится.

Comment: @Qwertiy нипанимать. То есть, остальные вопросы и примечания тоже адресованы мне? Тогда как они связаны с этим ответом?

Comment: @Qwertiy >> Мы поощряем написание кода примера прямо в вопросе? << таки да, поощряем, а когда код пишется на стороннем сайте или идёт в виде ссылки то не поощряем, только как дополнение возможно. Где ещё публиковать код C# как не в вопросе? Если HTML код, то можно в сниппете, но опять же не всегда это возможно, есть ситуации когда нельзя написать самодостаточный ответ запускаемый в сниппете.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, написание != копирование. Написал код в IDE, убедился, что проблема воспроизводится, скопипастил в вопрос - так хорошо. Написал какой-то код прямо в вопросе, отвечающий его себе копирует, правит десяток опечаток, наконец запускает, а проблема из вопроса и не воспроизводится - да ну нафиг. Автоформаттер кода поощряет второй способ. Зачем?