# Странное поведение сайта при вставке фрагмента кода

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, форматирование

Так как это ресурс для программистов, то значит что большинство вопросов здесь можно встретить именно по программированию. И у меня есть вопрос по поводу вставки кода в вопрос или ответ. Я уже не первый раз замечаю, что код очень неохотно подвергается принятому на сайте форматированию. На панели инструментов есть кнопка с парой кавычек, при нажатии на которую ваш код автоматически становится выделен серым цветом. Еще есть способ - нажатие на сочетание клавиш `ctrl+K`  если я правильно понял то это как бы аналог нажатия на кавычки.

Вот у меня уже не первый раз код просто никак не хочет форматироваться, ни нажатие на кавычки, ни сочетание клавиш, ничего не помогает. Единственное что меня немного спасло так это вручную вставлять кавычки перед началом и после конца моего кода. Вот мой последний ответ [Как изменить углы у кнопки в Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/881450/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-android). Как можно заметить, код в ответе не очень красивый.

И **самое непонятное** это то, что как-только до моего вопроса или ответа добирается модератор, то у него все правильно выглядит. Либо у него (модератора) есть какие-то секретные приемчики, либо это глюк сайта, либо это глюк моего браузера (Google Chrome), либо это мой личный глюк))

Как можно бороться с этой проблемой?

Answer (score 3):

Для того, чтобы фрагментам кода корректно отображаться внутри нумерованного списка надо вручную ещё добавить по 4 пробела для каждной строки кода (помимо четырёх по умолчанию). К сожаленью, встроенными средствами этого не достичь, поэтому это придётся делать либо вручную (как в данном случае, так как текста довольно мало), либо скопировав текст в какой-то продвинутый текстовый редактор (когда текста слишком много, чтобы это делать для каждой строки).

Я исправил ситуацию для приведённого случая.

Comment: Можно проще: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6884/178988 & https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4574/178988